# How using select Query in Python?

Tags: python, select

How can i use a **SELECT** Query in Python ?

*I just need a very sample example !*

Example in PHP :

```
$query = $db_connection -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = :name");

    $query -> execute (array (":name" => $name));

    $rows = $query -> fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $id = $row["id"];
    }

    echo $id;
```

I need same function in Python where *name* is an input !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer :

```
query = ("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '%s'""" % (name))

cursor.execute (query)

results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
id = row[0]
print (id)
```